# ECB pattern (Entity,Control,Boundary) implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns, boundary, ecb-pattern

I'm learning about the **ECB pattern**. I've understood the concept of this pattern but i'm not sure about its implementation. I'm going to write a simple example:
I supposed to need a software which manages the customers of a shop. The customers are stored on a generic database.
Accoding to the ECB pattern i need to have the following classes

1)***Customer*** which represents the entity, with its attributes (name,surname,birthDate etc..)

2)***CustomerWindow*** which represents the boundary, with some labels, textfields, buttons and a table to show customers

3)***CustomerController*** which represents the logic with some methods (insert,delete etc...)

I should add also a ***CustomerDAO*** (implementing an interface, but my question is not about DAO) which manages the access to the database.
I would like to know the way this classes interact each other.
For example, supposing the *insertion* of a new customer, i suppose they interact like this:

1)The **CustomerWindow** "collects" the data written inside the textFields (name,surname ecc) and calls the method insert(String ....) of the **CustomerController**.

2)**The CustomerController** check if all data are ok (for example empty fields or format error). If they are ok, create a new **Customer** with that data and calls the method insert(Customer c) of the **CustomerDAO**.

3)The **CustomerDao** provide to insert the customer into the database

Obviously some of this operations could throw some exceptions but i think it's not important for this example, supposing inserted data are all valid.
**Is this the way the ECB pattern works? If not, how it works?**

I have a last question: 
Some of this classes should be static or i need to declare an instance of each of them? For example i think the CustomerController and the Customer DAO can be static. The CustomeWindows calls the CustomerController.insert(...) method which eventually calls the CustomerDAO.insert(...) method   (so i don't need to create a new CustomerController() or a new CustomerDAO(). **Is it right?**

I hope my english is pretty understandable. Please tell me if i've not been clear about something. Thank you all ;)

P.s. if you prefer i can write a code example